# Repeat set of questions in InquirerJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inquirerjs

Is there a way to reset the questions or have a certain answer direct the question to another previous question?

```
var questions = [{
{
  name: 'morefood',
  message: 'Do you want more food?',
  type: 'list',
  choices: [ 'Yes', 'No'],
},{
  name: 'choiceoffood',
  message: 'Which food do you want more of?',
  type: 'list',
  choices: [ 'Hamburgers', 'Fries', 'Hotdogs']
  when: function(answers) {
    return answers.morefood === 'Yes';
  }
}, {
  name: 'quantityoffood',
  message: 'How much more do you want?',
  type: 'input',
  when: function(answers) {
    return answers.quantityoffood === 'Yes';
  }
},{
  name: 'confirmfood',
  message: 'Do you still want more food?',
  type: 'list',
  choices: [ 'Yes', 'No'],   <=========== if yes then goes back to choiceoffood
}, 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little hacky, but I believe you have to handle that in your application logic.  For example:

```
const questionA = {
    type: 'input',
    message: 'Do you like fruit?',
    name: 'questionA',
}

const questionB = {
    type: 'input',
    message: 'What is your favorite fruit?',
    name: 'questionB',
}

const questionC = {
    type: 'input',
    message: 'what is your favorite candy?',
    name: 'questionC',
}

inquirer
    .prompt(questionA)
    .then(answers => {
        if (answers.questionA === 'yes') {
           return inquirer.prompt(questionB)
        } else {
           return inquirer.prompt(questionC)
        }
    })
    .then(answers => {
        if (answers.questionB) {
             return console.log(answers.questionB, 'is a great fruit');
        } 
        if (answers.questionC) {
            return console.log(answers.questionC, 'is a great candy');
        }
    })
```

UPDATE:

After looking at the docs a bit more, it seems 'when' is the correct solution for this.

> **when:** (Function, Boolean) Receive the current user answers hash and
>   should return true or false depending on whether or not this question
>   should be asked. The value can also be a simple boolean.